# Avoid Xcode from running build if building failed

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a weird issue with Xcode. Consider the following sequence:

- Build completed successfully (Let's call it `Snapshot A`).
- Running the simulator compiling `Snapshot A`
- Changing some code, which fails the compilers (Let's call it `Snapshot B`)
- Trying to run the app, It'll show me build errors but still runs `Snapshot A` for some reason

When I'm trying to build without running it will fail, but building and running will just use the last working snapshot. Does anyone have any idea how to avoid this behavior? Really confusing sometimes. Thank you!

Comment: figure it out? drives me mad

Comment: Yeah, same here!